# How to create Left side Menu bar in objective-C?

Tags: objective-c

How to create costume menu bar. is there any third party class available to create   menu bar?

Answer (score 1):

You can also use this library aryaxt/iOS-Slide-Menu:https://github.com/aryaxt/iOS-Slide-Menu

Answer (score 0):

Try SWRevealViewController 3rd party library.
http://bcdilumonline.blogspot.com/2014/03/drawer-view-ios-app-with.html

Answer (score 0):

Try using [APMultiMenu](https://github.com/aadeshp/APMultiMenu). I've used it and it's simple to use and follow